# Set a value of a class from another class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to set the value of a member of a class from another class using this snippet. Here is a sample of the code I'm trying to make work

```
class A
{
private:
int a;
public:
A()
{
    a = 0;
}
A(int val)
{
    a = val;
}
int GetA()
{
    return  a;
}

void SetA()
{
    a = 290;
}
};


class B
{

B(){};

 void SetB()
{
     A a;
     a.SetA();
}

};


int main(){
A a;
B b;
b.SetB();
cout << b.GetA();

}
```

How can I make this code pint out `290`.I currently prints out 0

Answer (score 0):

In `SetB` your `A` variable is a temporary that is destroyed when the function returns.

Comment: Do I need to pass the value by reference?

Comment: Yes, you need passing an instance of `class A` by reference.

Answer (score 0):

The way it is written in your snippet, your code won't compile, because `B` has no method `GetA()`.  From your use case (the code in `main()`), I suspect you *either* want `B` to inherit from `A`:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
  B() {];
  void SetB()
  {
    SetA();
  }
};
```

although that doesn't make too much sense, because in this case you could just call `b.SetA()` directly.  *Or*, you want an object of type `A` as a *member* of `B`:

```
class B
{
public:
  void SetB()
  {
    a.SetA();
  }
  int GetA()
  {
    return a.GetA();
  }
private:
  A a;
};
```

But it's a bit hard to tell from your snippet what you're actually trying to achieve.

Also, you probably want your `Get…()` methods to be `const`.

Answer (score 0):

If you;re trying to achieve what I think you're trying to achieve then you're nearly there, it is just that you are creating two versions of A, one on the main stack, and one that is a temporary inside B::SetA()

try passing A as a reference parameter to B, so that there is only one version of A.

```
void SetB(A& a)
{
     a.SetA();
}
```

then your calling code would be:

```
A a;
B b;
b.SetB(a);
cout << a.GetA();
```

Alternatively, pass a in the constructor of B and store A as a reference member in B;